# How to put values from ArrayList in certain ranges?

Tags: java, arraylist, range

Is it possible to put values from my ArrayList into a specific ranges?

My ArrayList contains doubles:

```
0.4987873968412172
0.49949149542775684
0.4995227496071881
0.4999386804321369
0.500520813392628
0.5005912302221284
0.5006590304457654
0.5009476185730563
0.5013192031470984
```

And I want to divide them into (for example) two ranges to get an output:

```
Numbers from 0.498 to 0.499
0.4987873968412172
0.49949149542775684
0.4995227496071881
0.4999386804321369

Numbers from 0.500 to 0.501
0.500520813392628
0.5005912302221284
0.5006590304457654
0.5009476185730563
0.5013192031470984
```

Comment: What problem, use HashMap or List<List> and divide to two ranges in for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Integer> range1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> range2 = new ArrayList<>();
for(Integer i: myArrayList) 
  if(i < 0.5) range1.add(i);
  else range2.add(i);
```

Comment: Thank You, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `if` and `else`

```
if (number > 0.498 && number < 0.499) {
    firstArrayList.add(number);
}
else
{
    secondArrayList.add(number);
}
```

And if you have 3 (or more) ranges use `else if`

```
if (number > 0.498 && number < 0.499) {
    firstArrayList.add(number);
}
else if (number > 0.500 && number < 0.501)
{
    secondArrayList.add(number);
}
else
{
    thirdArrayList.add(number);
}
```